# How to show data from another table with foreign key CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller, foreign-keys, cakephp-3.0

I have the following tables:

1. users: id, name, ...
2. courses: id, name, knowledge_area_id, educational_institution_id, ...
3. users_courses: user_id, course_id, ...
4. knowledge_areas: id, name
5. educational_institutions: id, name, ...

I am currently trying to display on users' view some information about that user, including every course they are related to. Here is what I am currently doing:

On `/Template/Users/view.ctp`:

```
<?php foreach($user->courses as $courses): ?>
    <?= h($courses->name) ?>
    <?= h($courses->knowledge_area_id) ?>
    <?= h($courses->educational_institution_id ?>
    <?= h($courses->description) ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This shows every course the user is related to with it's name, the knowledge area ID, the educational institution ID and the course description. However, I would like to show the knowledge area's name and the educational institution's name instead of their ID. I have tried doing `$courses->knowledge_area->name` but it says I am trying get property `name` from a Non-Object.

When I try `debug($courses)` I get:

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Course) {

    'id' => (int) 2,
    'name' => 'course name',
    'knowledge_area_id' => (int) 1,
    'educational_institution_id' => (int) 1,
    'description' => 'course description',
    '_joinData' => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {
    ...
}
```

When in reality I should be getting

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Course) {

    'id' => (int) 2,
    'name' => 'course name',
    'knowledge_area_id' => (int) 1,
    'educational_institution_id' => (int) 1,
    'description' => 'course description',
    'educational_institution' => object(App\Model\Entity\EducationalInstitution) {

        'id' => (int) 1,
        'address_id' => (int) 1,
        'name' => 'ed institution name',
        '[new]' => false,
        '[accessible]' => [
            'address_id' => true,
            'name' => true,
            'address' => true,
            'courses' => true,
            'users' => true
        ],
        '[dirty]' => [],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[invalid]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'EducationalInstitutions'

    },
    'knowledge_area' => object(App\Model\Entity\KnowledgeArea) {

        'id' => (int) 1,
        'name' => 'knowledge area name',
        '[new]' => false,
        '[accessible]' => [
            'name' => true,
            'courses' => true
        ],
        '[dirty]' => [],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[invalid]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'KnowledgeAreas'

    },
...
}
```

That way, I would be able to use `$courses->knowledge_area->name`, which is basically what happens on `/Template/Courses/view.ctp`, where for each course I am able to show which knowledge area it is related to.

Since I am following cake conventions and I double checked the files I am assuming everything on `/Model/Table/..` and on the controllers is correct, any ideas on what I could do to fix this?

Comment: Please provide us the query code you've used to get the data.

Comment: I did not use a query, I'm just using the entity cakePHP creates for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Mary's comment, I managed to find a slightly different solution that worked for me.

Since I was trying to edit the users view, I went into the view function on users controller and changed

`$user = $this->Users->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Addresses',
                          'AccessLevels', 
                          'Courses', 
                          'EducationalInstitutions'
            ]
        ]);`

to

`$user = $this->Users->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Addresses',
                          'AccessLevels', 
                          'Courses', 
                          'EducationalInstitutions', 
                          'Courses.KnowledgeAreas', 
                          'Courses.EducationalInstitutions'
            ]
        ]);`

Comment: Yes, *you* found the answer.

Comment: Your answer did help me find it but it was not what directly worked for me (I couldn't manage to get find() working for some reason), hence why I upvoted it =) Thank you for the help, I appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

You can eager load associations as deep as you like using `contain()`:

```
$query = $products->find()->contain([
    'Shops.Cities.Countries',
    'Shops.Managers'
]);
```

See here: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#eager-loading-associations-via-contain